# How can I get Lydia out of my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Why has Lydia moved into my home?

I bought Breezehome, furnished it, and moved into it with my new wife. I have not used Lydia as a follower for some gaming weeks now. However she has decided to make herself at home and pretty much moved in!

Any advice on getting rid of Lydia before I get wife trouble?

Comment: There are no fixed morals in this game! =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lydia's your housecarl (bodyguard), and lives in Breezehome. Outside of possible console solutions, there's really only two ways to get her to move elsewhere:

1. Recruit her into the Blades; my understanding is that she'll then make Blades HQ her home when she's not following you.
2. Marry her and move into another house you own. Not really an option for you at this point, however, as you're already married.

Your only other option, I think, is to simply accept that you and your wife have a live-in bodyguard thanks to your position as Thane of Whiterun. It's not really anything for the wifey to get upset about -- Lydia even has her own separate bedroom! In fact, having a housecarl is definitely a sign of honor and privilege, so your wife should be rather pleased with the situation!

Comment: Ahh now it makes sense :) I thought it was some bug !! To be honest, as long as the 'two ladies' can live under one roof. Am fine with it I guess :)  Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Terry note also that only your wife will sleep in your bed.. Lydia should be sleeping in the guest room.

Comment: Option 3. If you have Hearthfire DLC, you can build a Homestead in another hold. You can make then make Lydia the Steward of one of those Homesteads and she would then live there instead. Alternatively, move yourself and your wife to the Homestead, Lydia will stay at Breezehome unless you bring her to the Homestead and make her Steward.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to recruit her as your follower once more and head out to the nearest dungeon so you can practice your fireballs. Accidents do happen...

Comment: I know lol. Even though am in the Dark Brotherhood I would feel a bit guilty .... or would I ?

Answer (score 0):

I bought the Breeze home in whiterun, and shortly afterwards, I got married.  My wife will usually talk to Lydia, so it doesn't bother her.  But, I plan to surprise my wife by adopting a child, but nowhere for her to sleep because Lydia took her bedroom.

The only way I know to get rid of her:  Have her follow you to a random location, and tell her to wait here, and she'll just stay there for awhile.

Comment: I like this solution because it answers the original question of how to get her out of the house.

Comment: @JoethePerson only for a few days, and you would need to go followerless (a waiting follower is still a follower as far as the game is concerned).

Comment: No, the children sleep in the downstairs bedroom. If you have an alchemy room, you need to remodel it into a children’s bedroom before you can adopt any children.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PC version, you can console, click on her, and type "Markfordelete".
Exit the house, return and she'll be gone.